# I am getting 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable when I use range() function

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am getting this error "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" in Jupyter notebook when I use the range() function in a very simple for loop. What's the problem?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
Input In [60], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for i in range(100):
      2     print(I)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you had declared some variable with the name "range". You should change the variable name to a different one if you would like to use the function range().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).